# Problemas com contador de caracteres de textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou querendo melhorar essa função, pois quando se quebra a linha, ela não conta os caracteres adequadamente:

```
$(function(){

    $("#maxlength").keyup(function(event){

        var target = $("#content-countdown");
        var max = target.attr('title');
        var len = parseInt($(this).val().length);
        var remain = max - len;

        if (len > max) {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(val.substr(0, max));

            remain = 0;
        }

        target.html(remain);

    });

});
```

HTML

```
<textarea name="body" maxlength="100" id="maxlength" placeholder="O que está acontecendo?"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Post">
<span id="content-countdown" title="100">100</span>
```

Comment: Quando ele quebra a linha ele não conta  ou conta ? por que quando se quebra a linha ele esta dando espaços esses espaços são contados como caracteres

Comment: quando eu quebro a linha até o máximo ele só conta 50 caracteres, mas não dá mais para digitar.

Comment: fiz um teste aqui e não achei esse problema... http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/tv0rrv0r/

Comment: No textarea segura enter até ele parar, aparece 50, quero que fique 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o Fiddle criado pelo Gabriel Rodrigues; fiz algumas alterações, removendo o maxlength do textarea(o que causava a limitação das linhas, não sei o motivo) e mudei o evento de keydown para input; que também será disparado quando texto for colado dentro do Textarea.

Pode conferir o resultado abaixo:

http://jsfiddle.net/tv0rrv0r/1/

EDIT:
Ao que parece é um bug do Webkit. Considerando que no windows uma quebra de linha equivale aos caracteres \r\n (carriage return e line feed), acredito que ao contabilizar a quantidade de caracteres as quebras de linha sejam contadas como dois caracteres e não um.
No Opera acontece o mesmo problema.